In a finite ring, a unit isn’t a zero factor, vice versa.
We know that in a finite ring, every non-zero element is either a unit or a zero factor.
Does there exists an element is both a unit and a zero factor?
For instance, suppose that: in a finite ring, we have ab = 1 and we want to show a is not a zero factor and ba = 1.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It has been proved that every nonzero element in a finite ring is either a unit or a zero divisor. See click me!

No. Suppose that $x$ is both a unit and a zero divisor in a commutative ring $R$. I.e, here exist both $w \neq 0$ and $u \neq 0$ such that $wx = 0$ and $xu=1$, then
$$w =  w(xu) = (wx)u=0. $$

If ab=0, ba=0? i.e. xw=0 and xu=1

Please don't answer problem statement questions and duplicates. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards

I think my question is not the duplicate as the one listed above. My question is , in any ring, can a unit itself be a zero factor? I mean that it is not only a unit but a zero factor.

Your question has been answered there. Please read carefully.

That question used commutativity, but here we are talking about a random finite ring, so we can't have things like an inverse of both sides and we can't dirive ba = 1 from ab = 1

A unit has, by definition, a two-sided inverse (Wikipedia). So there is no issue. Also notice that, in any case, in a finite ring $ab=1$ always implies $ba=1$. See for example here.
